# Display US State Abbreviations instead of full name on openMapTiles map?

Tags: openmaptiles

I'm using a locally hosted openMapTiles server with a custom style based on positron.  I'm looking to have US State two letter abbreviations instead of State names on my maps.  Is that data able to be referenced?  If so, how do I pull it into the place_state layer?

I've tried these, but no abbreviations are shown.

`{iso_a2:latin}{iso_a2:nonlatin}`

`{abbrev:latin}{abbrev:nonlatin}`

How?